# I'm creating an API Gateway using terraform but the API gives {"message": "Internal server error"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to Terraform and implementing serverless architecture with API-Gateway,Lambda. When I create the API Gateway from console manually with same setting and linking the same lambda function, it works correctly. But it gives "Internal Server Error" when linking the same lambda function with rest api created via terraform.
Is there something missing in my apiGateway.tf file which I've missed.

Lambda function is working correctly.

" apiGateway.tf "

```
variable "stage_name" {
  default = "example"
  type    = string
}

variable "profile" {
    default = "Dev"
}

//####  Creating REST API  ####

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "airbnbAPI" {
  name = "airbnbAPI"
  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

//####  Create Resource  ####

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "listing" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "listing"
}

//#### Create Method GET  ####

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get" {
  rest_api_id       = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.id
  resource_id       = aws_api_gateway_resource.listing.id
  http_method       = "GET"
  authorization     = "NONE"
  api_key_required  = false
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration-get" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.listing.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.get.http_method
  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.getListLambda.invoke_arn
}

//####  Method Response  ####

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.listing.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.get.http_method
  status_code = "200"
  response_models = {
       "application/json" = "Empty"
   }
}

//####  Integration Response  ####

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "MyDemoIntegrationResponse" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.listing.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.get.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code
  response_templates = {
       "application/json" = ""
   } 
}

//####  Create Stage  ####

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "test" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment1.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.id
  stage_name    = var.profile
}

//######  Deploy API Gateway  ######

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment1" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode(aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.body))
  }

  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_integration.integration-get]
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

//####  Creating trigger for Lambda for REST API  ####

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
   statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
   action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   function_name = aws_lambda_function.getListLambda.function_name
   principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

   /# The "/*/*" portion grants access from any method on any resource
   /# within the API Gateway REST API.

   source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.airbnbAPI.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

/# Output with invoke URL

output "complete_invoke_url"   {value = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment1.invoke_url}${aws_api_gateway_stage.test.stage_name}/${aws_api_gateway_resource.listing.path_part}"}
```

Images and screenshots

[Creating API Gateway manually from console working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIAE9.png)

[API Gateway Rest API Created via Terraform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVS0A.png)

[Expected Output from RestAPI getting correctly when creating API from console manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UAlA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. Apparently GET function does not work(APIGW --> Lambda) instead had to use POST function. Getting the output as expected when using POST.

Found the following link which made me realize it was not me :D
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9271